# How to use intern test html5 text input event?

Tags: intern

I want to active ime and input chinese.
How to trigger compositionStart, compositionUpdate,compositionEnd.
I use this.remote.type([]) method, but not trigger text input events.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The IME must be activated independently, just like on the real OS, before type commands will be processed through it. Unfortunately, the underlying WebDriver library used by Intern [does not currently implement IME activation](https://github.com/admc/wd/issues/180). Once it does, you will be able to activate and test IMEs with Intern.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to add new methods to wd. There is a guide at the end of the README: https://github.com/admc/wd#adding-new-method--contributing

Once it is done just, open a pull request and that will go into the npm package pretty quickly. This is how most of the existing methods were added to wd.